# htaccess: Display same content on every page (masking)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how would a .htaccess look if I wanted to display the same content on every URL? For example, no matter whether the user types url.com, url.com/index.php, url.com/path or even url.com/some/path/on/the/server.html, it always should display the content of **url.com/index.php**.

I tried to do so with this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php
```

But this didn't seem to have any effect at all. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule .* /index.php [QSA,L]
```

Also you can exclude some static files like images or css using the following conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
```